# Upgrading from OpenGL 3.0 to 3.3+ on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card

I recently made the switch from Windows to Ubuntu (because I am becoming more of a game developer than a game player), but quickly found out that my OpenGL version was downgraded because of the switch. It used to be **3.3 or 3.4**, but now it is at **3.0**. Is there a way I can **upgrade my OpenGL** through new drivers? I know my graphics card supports GL3.* (It is a **Radeon HD6570** chipset) but I'm thinking it may be simply a support issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved — all I did was run `Additional Drivers`, which came up with the proper FGLRX proprietary graphics card drivers. The experimental driver had the GL version I needed.

Answer (score 1):

For your card (driver is named r600g) is OpenGL still in development.

- You should get OpenGL 3.1 with Mesa 10.1 version.
- With actual development version (pre 10.2) there should be [complete OpenGL 3.3](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/docs/GL3.txt) support for your card.

In Ubuntu, you may get development version by installing [oibaf ppa](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/).

Also you'll need [3.14 linux kernel](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTU5NDM) for OpenGL 3.2/3.3 support. For Ubuntu you can get prepared kernel from [kernel ppa](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/), howto is [here](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/04/install-upgrade-to-linux-kernel-3-14-in-linux.html), only replace with lastest 3.14.y version.